# PHP GD how to draw text over a line

Tags: php, gd

The final output should be like image(HELLO WORLD):
[image: Ignore the line thickness Please..]

Here is what i am doing:-

```
$im = imagecreate(400,400); 

$txtcol = imagecolorallocate($im, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00);

$size = 20;

$txt = 'DUMMY TEXT';

$font = './font/Capriola-Regular.ttf';

/*two points for base line*/

$x1 = 50; $x2 = 300; 

$y1 = 150; $y2 = 170;

/*bof finding line angle*/

$delta_x = $x2-$x1;

$delta_y = $y2-$y1;

$texangle = (rad2deg(atan2($delta_y,$delta_x)) * 180 / M_PI)-360;

/*eof finding the line angle*/


imageline($im,$x1,$y1,$x2,$y2,$txtcol); //Drawing line

imagettftext($im, $size, $texangle, $x1, $y1, $txtcol, $font, $txt); // Drawing text over line at line's angle
```

And current output is like:

[image: Current output]

Can anybody tell whats the wrong with my code?

THanks

Comment: Where is `$ty` defined in `imagettftext`?

Comment: Sorry that not $ty its $y1
@webnoob thanks for notifying me :)

Comment: I think the problem is with finding the Line angle. what do you think @webnoob

Comment: Yes, that line is causing problems. I'm not in a position to test it at the moment so can't really help without running the code directly.

Comment: @Robin:Try to give the angle (-)eve value and check

Comment: @zamil tried but it didn't work. :(

Comment: @ROBIN: are you hard coding the x and y values of the line an text?

Comment: @ROBIN - Added a solution below. It was as you thought, the angle was being calculated incorrectly.

Comment: @zamil Initially i was testing so took the hard coded value.

Comment: @ROBIN - Don't forget to mark it as an answer if it's worked for you. Helps people identify the correct solutions to problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, been playing around. Try replacing:

```
$texangle = (rad2deg(atan2($delta_y,$delta_x)) * 180 / M_PI)-360;
```

With:

```
$texangle = (atan2($delta_y,$delta_x) * -180 / M_PI)-360;
```

Output with your values:

[image]

Output with other values:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not the exact thing what you may be looking for, but i believe it will help you

```
$im = imagecreate(400,400); 

$txtcol = imagecolorallocate($im, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00);

$size = 20;

$txt = 'DUMMY TEXT';

$font = 'Capriola-Regular.ttf';

/*two points for base line*/

$x1 = 70; $x2 = 170; 

$y1 = 140; $y2 = 240;

/*bof finding line angle*/

$delta_x = $x2-$x1;

$delta_y = $y2-$y1;

$texangle = (rad2deg(atan2($delta_y,$delta_x)) * 180 / M_PI)-360;

/*eof finding the line angle*/


imageline($im,$x1,$y1,$x2,$y2,'0xDD'); //Drawing line
imagettftext($im, $size, -45, $x1, $y1-10, '0xDD', $font, $txt); // Drawing text over line at line's angle

header('Content-Type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

values are hard coded.
Here the angle is given as -45 and for that angle if you want your text to appear above line you have to reduce the value from initial Y position of your line.
And you will have to write code to calculate the angle with line's x1,x2y1,y2

Comment: Thats works. Initially i was testing so i take the hard coded values. Now the question is if we are providing Line's cordinates dynamically then how we are going to find the angle for imagettftext and REDUCED value of Y ?

Comment: @Robin:i think webnoob's solution should work.i have not tested it though

Answer (score 1):

2 thoughts, can't test right now.

1. Where is 0 (x=1, y=0) or (x=0, y=1). It seems your text is off by 90
   degrees which usually means that your assuming 0 is directly right,
   when maybe it's directly up or vice versa.
2. `(rad2deg(atan2($delta_y,$delta_x)) * 180 / M_PI)-360;` are you doing double work here? `rad2deg` converts from radians to degrees.  `180 / M_PI` is also a conversion from radians to degrees.